# Magento CE :: Discount on First Order?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Is there any plausible way to give a customer a discount on their first order?

I imagine it would require the user to sign up for a free account, which is fine. But after that, I'm stumped.

The Promotion feature in Magento doesn't cater for anything like this and Google doesn't find any good leads.

Ideas?

:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing out of the box to do this, but the general approach I'd take would be

1. Create a catalog price rule for your "first time" discount
2. Add an attribute to the customer object named something like "used_first_coupon".  Defaults to 0/false
3. Add an event on customer creation that send the coupon code to the customer
4. Hook into the coupon applying code (if there's an event, use it, otherwise, rewrite whatever method you need to) and only apply the specific coupon if the logged in customer's used_first_coupon is false
5. Add an event listener post-order that will mark the customers used_first_coupon attribute as true

Comment: Alan, you got mistake in the 5th step, `used_first_coupon` should be set to `true` :)

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about the same thing. In Magento Community 1.7. I think this should work.

1. Create a discount - with no coupon - and specify in setup that it can be used only once.
2. Assign this discount to the default group.

It should then be applied to every new user and can only be used once.